# Applescript editor can't look for a file

Tags: applescript

I needed to write some codes to do this, but Applescript editor can't see if the file (ewqe_file) is existed or not. (It is existed)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
set fullPath to (POSIX path of (path to desktop folder as text)) & "aFolderOnMyDesktop/44034_D.pdf"
tell application "System Events"
    if exists file fullPath then
        log fullPath
        -- do your stuff
    end if
end tell
```

`path to` command, from StandardAdditions:

```
path to v : Return the full path to the specified folder
path to application support/applications folder/desktop/desktop pictures folder/documents folder/downloads folder/favorites folder/Folder Action scripts/fonts/help/home folder/internet plugins/keychain folder/library folder/modem scripts/movies folder/music folder/pictures folder/preferences/printer descriptions/public folder/scripting additions folder/scripts folder/services folder/shared documents/shared libraries/sites folder/startup disk/startup items/system folder/system preferences/temporary items/trash/users folder/utilities folder/workflows folder/voices/apple menu/control panels/control strip modules/extensions/launcher items folder/printer drivers/printmonitor/shutdown folder/speakable items/stationery : the folder to return
[from system domain/local domain/network domain/user domain/Classic domain] : where to look for the indicated folder
[as type class] : the type to return: alias or string (default is alias)
[folder creation boolean] : Create the folder if it doesn’t exist? (default is true)
→ alias : the path to the specified folder
```

Comment: It's a POSIX path! Just use the style you used first to add the part after desktop, like "Application Support/Hash Remover/..." (that's Posix Style)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. one more thing: what if it is in ~/Library/Application support/hash remover/... ?

Comment: You can use "(path to application support folder as text)" or any of the specifications the "path to" command understands (there are many).

Answer (score 0):

The path should be written in this format:

```
"Macintosh HD:Users:username:Desktop:file.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I updated my post. take a look

Comment: Don't use POSIX path with 'exists file', only the ':' format